# Git asking for private key?

Tags: ssh, password, git, authentication, keys

I'm on Ubuntu and I'm learning how to use Git collaboratively.

I have created a pair of public/private keys on my local Ubuntu desktop with the following command:

```
ssh-keygen -b 2048
```

I then accessed my public key with:

```
cat /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Following instructions I found online, I created a repository on GitHub and went to the Settings and added my public key.

I then wanted to do 2 things:

1) Check that my authentication is working well with GitHub. I did this by typing:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I get the following output, to which I answered "yes"

```
# The authenticity of host 'github.com (xxxx)' can't be established.
# RSA key fingerprint is xxxxx.
# Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? Yes
```

I then get a pop window saying:

```
An application wants to access the private key "user@ubuntu" but it is locked. 
It then asks for a password.
```

2) Do a Git push to my newly created remote repository.

```
# First, I connect my local repository to my remote GitHub one (this works)
$ git remote add origin git@github.com:username/repository_name.git

# Next, I try and push my local commits to the repository_name:
$ git push origin master
```

I then get the same pop-up window as in 1), asking for access to my private key and a password.

My questions are:

- Is this normal? I'm very new to the concept of public/private keys and rapid anthentication but I thought that I should never share my private key? So why is Git asking for it?
- If I need to give it, is Git asking for my Git password or my key password (a password I would have set up when making my public/private keys)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this normal? I'm very new to the concept of public/private keys and rapid anthentication but I thought that I should never share my private key? So why is Git asking for it?

You should never share your private key. However, what these applications want you to do is unlock your private key locally, not send it to a different computer.

> If I need to give it, is Git asking for my Git password or my key password (a password I would have set up when making my public/private keys)

There is no git password. You probably mean your GitHub password.

You could log in via the username and password of your GitHub account. However, using public key authentication is easier and better. When you created your key pair, you chose a password. This is the password you need to enter. You'll probably only have to do this once per session because your SSH agent will store it for you. If you're prompted for it repeatedly in the same session (a session being the time between when you log into your computer and when you log out), you should add your key pair to your SSH agent:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Answer (score 0):

if you mean the private key chain in linux; then you probably have to enter the "phrase" that you entered before 
it prompts to you like this

> Enter passphrase 
>   Enter same passphrase again: